# How to slice dynamic text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem. I want to remove certain characters from a string in javascript.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
var stringName = "101 Naga City (D23)";
```

I want to remove the "(D23)" from the string:

```
stringName.slice(0, -5);
```

The code above works well, but, the string can be dynamic like:

```
var stringName = "101 Naga City (D232131)";
```

Or

```
var stringName = "101 Naga City (9122312)";
```

I want to dynamically remove the "(" and ")" including the contents inside.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: look up `String.indexOf` and `String.lastIndexOf` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: Either locate the position of the () characters or use a regular expression.

Comment: @KopaxJackHerrauer I wouldn't say must, but yes it'd be much better to use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 var stringName = "101 Naga City (D23)";
 stringName = stringName.substring(0, stringName.indexOf('('));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PzESw/112/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling adventurous try this regex:

```
var stringName = "101 Naga City (D23)";
stringName = stringName.replace(/(\s*\(.*\))/, "");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CD3U3/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex

```
var str="101 Naga City (D23dzadzad2131)"
var n=str.search(/\(.*\)/i);
str = str.slice(0,n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try RegExp,

```
stringName = "101 Naga City (D23)";
s = stringName.replace(/ \(.*\)/, '');        // s = '101 Naga City'

stringName = "101 Naga City (D232131) XXX";
s = stringName.replace(/ \(.*\)/, '');        // s = '101 Naga City XXX'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s8zw4/

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringName = "101 Naga City (D23)";

stringName = stringName.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)/,"");

alert(stringName);
```

Explanation...

Use regular expression to replace unwanted parts. Match pattern, and replace with empty string... `stringName.replace(<pattern>,"")`

Regular expression to match unwanted part...

```
/    # start regex
\s*  # zero or more space characters
\(   # open bracket (escaped)
.*?  # zero or more of anything, ungreedily (match as few as possible)
\)   # close bracket
/    # end pattern
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eqq-Ak9QJ4A8UA64)

[JSFiddle working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/JA9CL/)